# How do I change background color of li elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/oski369/2Lzc6q95/

When I plug it into js fiddle, the background color of each li changes according to it's class (even or odd) as I want them to.  However when I run the same code in my browser the background colors are ignored.  I also note that in the fiddle the "cover" property I put in my background-image is ignored while it works fine in my browser.

I am using bootstrap in my text editor while obviously that is not the case in fiddle.  Idk if this could be the issue but how would I accomplish the same alternating color change between list items that appears in the fiddle in my text editor?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/animate.min.css"/>
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
 <link href="css/stockData.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="text-primary">
  <h1 >StockData</h1>
  <div class="row" id="stockTable">
    <ul>
       <li class="odd">
        <span class="col-md-4">Ticker</span> 
        <span class="col-md-4">% Change</span> 
        <span class="col-md-4">Position</span>
      </li> 
      <li class="even">
        <a class="col-md-4">AAPL</a>
        <span class="col-md-4">+3%</span>
        <span class="col-md-4"> <span class="holding">5.4</span><span>%</span> <span>Short</span></span>
      </li>
      <li class="odd">
        <span class="col-md-6">Portfolio</span> 
        <span class="col-md-6">+2.4%</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
   <script src="stockData.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#stockTable {
    width:38%;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
.odd{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}
.even{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
body{
    background-image:url('http://evilcorps.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/wall_street_1920.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
h1{
    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

Comment: when you are in your browser, have you gone to the DOM explorer and checked the CSS of those list elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `span` and `a` tags you are defining the bootstrap columns with `class="col-md-4"` or `class="col-md-6"` respectively. Try giving the `li` tags a row of their own to house those columns.

```
<li class="odd row">
  <span class="col-md-4">Ticker</span> 
  <span class="col-md-4">% Change</span> 
  <span class="col-md-4">Position</span>
</li> 
<li class="even row">
  <a class="col-md-4">AAPL</a>
  <span class="col-md-4">+3%</span>
  <span class="col-md-4"> <span class="holding">5.4</span><span>%</span>    <span>Short</span></span>
</li>
<li class="odd row">
  <span class="col-md-6">Portfolio</span> 
  <span class="col-md-6">+2.4%</span>
</li>
```

[Here's a demo on boot.ply](http://www.bootply.com/yIxZrdKQCi) that should have all your bootstrap code built in.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly, you want to give background colour to to children of list item li depending on whether they are odd or even.

You should use nth-child in css on the children of list item li to accomplish this.

You should try something like this:

1) The css style given below will make the background of all even children as blue.

```
li span:nth-child(2n){
    background:#00f;
}
```

2)The css style given below will make the background of all odd children as white.

```
li span:nth-child(2n+1){
    background: #fff;
}
```

i hope that helps :)

Answer (score -2):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
.odd{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.8) !important;
}

.even{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.6) !important;
}
```

"!important" will override any other styles.

---

OK, so if it's considered a hack, then I think the only way for you to do that is to change values in Bootstrap.css or do it with your own classes or something like this:

```
li { 
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

li:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
```

While you should remove .odd and .even class or it won't work. You can give to ul your own class and then write ul.class-name li { } in CSS instead of li to make it change only this specific ul's li colors.

Comment: this may be a hack, but I don't think it deserves downvotes in this case.  It may help the OP.

Comment: Since when there are hacks in CSS? O.o

Comment: This really isn't good advice for someone who is genuinely stuck. !important is like turning on the cheat mode when you're playing a game - it's a useful tool when you want to work out how to solve one particular thing (without having to deal with all the other things) but it really isn't "production-grade" CSS. In the long run it will lead to ingrained bad habits. Far better to learn the cascade, inheritance and specificity properly.

Comment: It could be good advice, though - as long as it comes with the caveat: "if this works, it means something else is overriding your CSS, so it's better if you find it and figure out the real issue."  But I think there's a good chance the OP may not care about "production-grade" CSS.

Comment: I changed it, I hope it's okay :)

Comment: Thank you, OP here.  Andi you're right it is good advice with that caveat.         But I am trying to learn to be the best I can be, especially when I ask a question here, so I do appreciate other users' concerns over giving "production-grade" advice.

Comment: And while I definitely learned something from this answer and appreciate it, doing as you said didn't instantly fix my problem thats why I had to give the best answer to wmeade